# I want to update null value as well in table if i explicitly pass in PLSQL in parameter

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have created a PLSQL procedure and below is the short code snippet of the same. In below if I'm sending amount as null then I want to update the amount column in table as null, but i have added NVL here as the parameter is optional to pass while calling this procedure. How can I have NVL and also if a user passes null in parameter then i want to update that column as null? Please help

```
DECLARE
    V_BATCH_NUMBER VARCHAR2(100) := '2024-3';
    V_AMOUNT       VARCHAR2(500) := null;
    V_NAME     VARCHAR2(500);
    V_REGION_NAME  VARCHAR2(100) := 'New York';
BEGIN
    UPDATE BATCH_DETAILS_TAB
    SET
        TOTAL_AMOUNT = NVL(
            V_AMOUNT,
            TOTAL_AMOUNT
        ),
        NAME = NVL(
            V_NAME,
            NAME
        ),
        REGION_NAME = NVL(
            V_REGION_NAME,
            REGION_NAME
        )
    WHERE
        BATCH_NUMBER = V_BATCH_NUMBER;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Here V_AMOUNT is null and i want to update the total_amount column as null but here it is not overriding.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? (I doubt the above code will execute on both...)

Answer (score 1):

> if I'm sending amount as null then I want to update the amount column in table as null,

OK; which means that *whatever* you pass to `V_AMOUNT` should end in `TOTAL_AMOUNT` column

> but i have added NVL here as the parameter is optional to pass while calling this procedure

That's just the opposite of what you previously said. `NVL` function will check its 1st parameter's value. If it is `NULL`, then `NVL` will return value of the second parameter. In your case, it means that `TOTAL_AMOUNT` will remain what it previously was (i.e. nothing will change).

Therefore, you need just

```
UPDATE BATCH_DETAILS_TAB SET TOTAL_AMOUNT = V_AMOUNT ...
```

Comment: No, If I don't send any value then it must not override the previous value

Comment: Aha; seems I misunderstood what you were saying. If that's the case, then `NVL(V_AMOUNT, TOTAL_AMOUNT)` should do. NULL means *absence of value*; if user "sends" NULL, NVL will take affect and actually do nothing. You can't have both; NULL is NULL, regardless of whether someone passes it to procedure or you set V_AMOUT variable's value to NULL. How can you tell the difference? It's just V_AMOUNT you're dealing with, it doesn't say what's its source. Perhaps you could do what you described using TWO parameters/variables - one set by user, another by you, and then decide what to do.

Comment: Thank you, any solution or hint can you please provide as i'm not very good at PLSQL. suppose if i pass null then it has to update null overriding previous value and if i send nothing then it should not modify existing value (happening currently with NVL)

Comment: @mushaikh We had a similiar problem and if I remember correctly there was no other way then to use a default parameter that is very unlikely to be passed as parameter. This default value then gets checked, if it is the default value it means no parameter was explicitly passed and you can use the column name in your dml. 
TOTAL_AMOUNT = case when v_amount = default value then TOTAL_AMOUNT else v_amount end;

We had package constants containing the defaults for the different data types and created overloaded methods. So you can do something like total_amount = dvl(v_amount, total_amount)